# An issue about instantiation context

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Consider the following example in [module.context p7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/module.context#7)

```cpp
//Translation unit #1:

export module stuff;
export template<typename T, typename U> void foo(T, U u) { auto v = u; }
export template<typename T, typename U> void bar(T, U u) { auto v = *u; }  

//Translation unit #2:

export module M1;
import "defn.h";        // provides struct X {};
import stuff;
export template<typename T> void f(T t) {
  X x;
  foo(t, x);
}

// Translation unit #3:

export module M2;
import "decl.h";        // provides struct X; (not a definition)
import stuff;
export template<typename T> void g(T t) {
  X *x;
  bar(t, x);
}

// Translation unit #4:

import M1;
import M2;
void test() {
  f(0);
  g(0);
}
```

For `f(0)`, the comment says that

> the instantiation context of foo<int, X> comprises
>
> > - the point at the end of translation unit #1,
> > - the point at the end of translation unit #2, and
> > - the point of the call to f(0),

I can understand the first point, because of this rule

> During the implicit instantiation of a template whose point of instantiation is specified as that of an enclosing specialization ([temp.point]), the instantiation context is the union of the instantiation context of the enclosing specialization and, **if the template is defined in a module interface unit of a module M and the point of instantiation is not in a module interface unit of M, the point at the end of the declaration-seq of the primary module interface unit of M (prior to the private-module-fragment, if any)**.

However, I cannot figure out the remaining points, especially the second one. How to interpret such two points?

#### UPDATE:

From the answers of @Nicol Bolas

> So "the instantiation context of the enclosing specialization" of `foo` is the instantiation context of `f`. **Which includes the end of TU2, pursuant to what you quoted and emphasized**.

I don't think the emphasized wording says the instantiation context of the enclosing specialization comprises "the end of TU2". I think the whole [module.context#3] should be parsed as that

> During the implicit instantiation of **a template T** whose point of instantiation is specified as that of an enclosing specialization ([temp.point]), the instantiation context is the union of the instantiation context of the enclosing specialization and, if **the template T** is defined in a module interface unit of a module M and the point of instantiation is not in a module interface unit of M, the point at the end of the declaration-seq of the primary module interface unit of M (prior to the private-module-fragment, if any).

The template `T` does not designate the template from which the enclosing specialization is instantiated.

Answer (score 4):

All of this goes back to what you quoted but didn't follow the link on: "enclosing specialization". From [[temp.point]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.point#1):

> For a function template specialization, a member function template specialization, or a specialization for a member function or static data member of a class template, if the specialization is implicitly instantiated because it is referenced from within another template specialization and the context from which it is referenced depends on a template parameter, the point of instantiation of the specialization is the point of instantiation of the enclosing specialization.

In TU2, the function template `foo` is specialized within the function template `f`. `f` is the "enclosing specialization" of `foo`.

So "the instantiation context of the enclosing specialization" of `foo` is the instantiation context of `f`. Which includes the end of TU2, pursuant to what you quoted and emphasized.

As for the third point... it's just the second point repeated for the use of `f`. `f(0)` specializes `f`, thereby acting as part of its instantiation context. Because `foo` is enclosed within `f`, this also acts as part of the instantiation context for `foo`.

Comment: Isn't that the point of instantiation of `f` should immediately follow `void test()` or at the end of TU4, as per [temp.point]/1? why the end of `TU2` is relevant here?

Comment: In other words, which bullet explicitly says the instantiation context of the specialization of `f` comprises the end of `TU2`?

Comment: For the question in the above comment, if you say it is specified by the emphasized wording I cited, I would say `the template` seems not to refer to the template for the enclosing specialization, instead, it should refer to the template **whose point of instantiation is specified as that of an enclosing specialization**.

Comment: Is there any thought here?

Comment: @xmh0511 grammatically,  in a sentence structured "**a** template* <action>, if  ***the** template* <action>", word *template* would refer to same subject, so that's correct. but rule has to be applied recursively for `f()` and `g()`.

Comment: @xmh0511 The instantiation at end of module still happens to facilitate global use of the template, it's a standardized way to implement  old trick of manual instantiation in *.cpp, which worked on some pre-ISO and early ISO-compatible compilers.  `f()` is instantiated at end of its module and at point of its use.  Its instantiation implicitly instantiates `foo()` as well. As `foo()` is from different module,  there is one extra point of instantiation.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie The rule does not apply recursively for `f()` and `g()`, although they are template specialization, they are not referred to **in an enclosing specialization**.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Incidentally, IIUC, "at end of its module" is Unit #2 while "at point of its use" is Unit #4? Which bullet says the point of instantiation of `f()` includes Unit #2?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Unless you mean that "the template" and "a template" in that rule do not completely refer to the same subject. You meant "the template" can refer to `f`, `g`, `foo`, `bar` in this case?

Comment: @xmh0511 To all of them, because *if the template is defined in a module interface unit of a module interface unit of a module M and the point of instantiation is not in a module interface unit* #2 and #3 applies to `f()` and `g()`, their context includes *the point at the end of the declaration-seq of the primary module interface unit* #2 and #3 respectively,  According to the quote cited by Nicol, the context of `f()` is a sub-set of contexts of enclosed specializations of `foo()`, i.e. the context of `foo()` would be context of `f()` extended by  the point at end of #1.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie So, you mean that "the template" and "a template" in that rule do not say the same subject?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238118/discussion-between-xmh0511-and-swift-friday-pie).